# JQuery Ajax POST Call to Jersey with Content Type JSON fails to execute

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post, jersey

I am having an issue with using jQuery's ajax call to post JSON data to my REST service.

Background:

Using jQuery 1.9.1

Using Firefox 27.0.1 (although seen on other earlier versions as well)

Using Jersey 1.1.5.1

I am attempting to call this method in my Jersey REST Service:

```
@POST
@Path("/items")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response createItem(@Context final ServletContext context, String body)
{
 ...
}
```

My jQuery ajax call is as follows. Note that the 'postData' string is just dummy json. I do the next line to convert it to an object, to make sure that I have valid JSON.

```
var callPost = function() {
  var postUrl = "https://otherhost:8443/package/service/items";
  var postData = '{"TEST":true,"success":false}';
  var postDataItem = JSON.parse(postData);
  console.info("Post Data Item as string: " + JSON.stringify(postDataItem));
  console.info("create post url: " + postUrl);
  var ajaxPostCall =
    $.ajax( { type: "POST",
              url: postUrl,
              data: JSON.stringify(postDataItem),
              contentType: "application/json",
              success:
                function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                  var statusC = jqXHR.status;
                  console.log("Done Status Code: " + statusC);
                  console.log("Done textStatus: " +  textStatus );
                  console.log("Done data: " +  JSON.stringify(data) );
                  console.log("Item Fetch Called");
                },
              error:
                function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                  var responseText = jqXHR.responseText;
                  console.log("Fail responseText: " + responseText);
                  var statusC = jqXHR.status;
                  console.log("Fail Status Code: " + statusC);
                  console.log("Fail textStatus: " +  textStatus );
                  console.log("Fail error: " +  errorThrown );
                }
              });
};
```

When I execute this call, here is what I see in the Firebug console:

Response 1:

```
(info) Post Data Item as string: {"TEST":true,"success":false}
(info) create post url: https://otherhost:8443/package/service/items
Fail responseText:
Fail Status Code: 0
Fail textStatus: error
Fail error:
```

'Response 1' leads me to believe that the ajax call is never actually sent to the server. If I remove the 'contentType: "application/json"' line, then this is what the console shows:

Response 2:

```
(info) Post Data Item as string: {"TEST":true,"success":false}
(info) create post url: https://otherhost:8443/package/service/items
POST https://otherhost:8443/package/service/items 415 Unsupported Media Type 18ms   
"NetworkError: 415 Unsupported Media Type - https://otherhost:8443/package/service/items"
Fail responseText:
Fail Status Code: 0
Fail textStatus: error
Fail error:
```

'Response 2' shows that the call was executed and the server rejected it, because the type was not successfully set as "json". It seems that for some reason, jQuery.ajax does not allow the contentType to be set as "application/json". To test this, I set 'contentType: "text/plain"' and the response was the same as 'Response 2'.

I am able to call the rest service using the RESTClient add-on for firefox successfully. I add a header for "Content-Type: application/json" and the body matches the json I am sending from jQuery and it succeeds, which shows me that the service is working correctly. I get a '415 Unsupported Media Type' (correctly) if I leave out the header for 'Content-Type'.

In order to make sure that the service was working and in fact this is a 'contentType: "application/json"' issue, I redeployed my service with the call expecting plain text:

```
@POST
@Path("/items")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response createItem(@Context final ServletContext context, String body)
{
 ...
}
```

And set 'contentType: "text/plain"' for the post call, and got back this successfully:

Response 3:

```
(info) Post Data Item as string: {"TEST":true,"success":true}
(info) create post url: https://otherhost:8443/package/service/items
POST https://otherhost:8443/package/service/items 200 OK 297ms  
Done Status Code: 200
Done textStatus: success
Done data: "Success creating Item: newItemId"
Item Fetch Called
```

'Response 3' came back as expected and succeeded.

I tested with bad json and got back the error from the service successfully.

Response 4:

```
(info) Post Data Item as string: {"TEST":true,"success":false}
(info) create post url: https://otherhost:8443/package/service/items
POST https://otherhost:8443/package/service/items 500 Internal Server Error 142ms   
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - https://otherhost:8443/package/service/items"
Fail responseText: Error creating Item: null
Fail Status Code: 500
Fail textStatus: error
Fail error: Internal Server Error
```

Does anyone know why setting the 'contentType' for the ajax POST call to 'application/json' would cause it not to execute at all?

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you are sending a stringified version of the JSON object instead of just the object? Try changing:

```
data: JSON.stringify(postDataItem)
```

to

```
data: postDataItem
```